# Unknown arguments error in Xamarin UITest

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center, xamarin.uitest, visual-studio-app-center-test

For my xamarin project I added a uitest test that will check how long it takes to load the app. What I try to upload the test to app center I get this error.

```
Error: Command 'test run uitest --app Appne-iOS --devices /ios-12 --app-path C:\pathtoipa.ipa --test-series master --locale en_US --build-dir c\....\App.UITests\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\' failed with exception "Unknown arguments: Nameofipafile.ipa"
```

Comment: Do you have Local Screenshots disabled? Are you using the latest stable (not preview) version of Visual Studio and all the other components? Do you have the latest Xamarin UI Test package?